# Hide Menu page in Landscape mode iPad master details page

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator, ipados

My app should work only on Landscape mode, till iOS 13 release it was working fine. After iOS 13, I noticed that the Master page (menu page) is visible on iPad screen as if I used split-screen. I tried MasterPage.MasterBehavior = popover and also tried MasterPage.IsPresented = false; none of these are working.

I tried MasterPage.MasterBehavior = popover and also tried MasterPage.IsPresented = false; none of these are working.

Also, I wanted to know how to catch the click event of the "Menu" button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how to catch the click event of the "Menu"
>   button.

You can listen to the `IsPresentedChanged` event:

```
 public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            masterPage.listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

            this.IsPresentedChanged += MainPage_IsPresentedChanged;

        }

        private void MainPage_IsPresentedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu Click");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Jack, any lights on hiding on master page (menu page)??

Comment: Are you using the latest Xamarin.forms version? It only happens when you use used split-screen?

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest Xamarin.forms. As I mentioned MasterPage.MasterBehavior = popover is already there. JFYI: I am noticing this behaviour since iOS 13, before that it was working as expected.

Comment: I've the same problem: my app works until iOS 12 but with iOS 13 (only on iPad) the menu don't disappear.

Comment: You guys can open an issue in Github if the problem still exist in the latest version.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT How you want me to open a ticket? also, how can I check the latest version ?

Comment: Is there a way that I an use iOS 12's runtime to run the code from xamarin, as if I built my app prior to iOS 13 release?

Comment: @user3496276 You can open a free Xamarin support case here:[xamarin support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6)

Comment: Any update on this issue? I am also facing this issue and trying to find a solution.